# Manage and structure Javascript code in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Because of my lack of experience in ASP.NET, I'm having a bad time structuring well my files in a way that makes it readable and maintanable, and I end up wasting a lot of time trying to find specific things I want to change in my script. There are many questions about how to structure an ASP.NET MVC application, a lot of them regarding to Javascript code, but they are mostly dated and things have evolved.

So I have a .cshtml page that requires a lot of front-end code (it uses Google Maps and lets you manage pins and location informations). How it currently works is every JS used in that page is just shoved in the `@section scripts` at the end of the file. I have minimum organization and that doesn't help me much.

```
@section scripts {
    @* Import Google Map API *@
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBfReMSOphvs4kdt81t39Pq5Y39z9MJPY0"></script>

    @* Manages the Navbar and SiteInfoNavbar *@
    <script>...</script>

    @* Manages the Map, SearchBoxes and Markers *@
    <script>...</script>

    @* Initializes the residues multiselect (in the site's info editing nav) and other html injections *@
    <script>...</script>

    @* Manages the alerts, spinners and modals *@
    <script>...</script>

    @* Manages business hours section for the selected site *@
    <script>...</script>

    @* Manages Ajax calls *@
    <script>...</script>

    @* Initialization *@
    <script>...</script>
}
```

One of the solutions I found was the [Garber-Irish](https://gist.github.com/danielgreen/5677251) Javascript structuring format, which seems to help when JS is scattered through pages. But, in my case, my problem is this one page and file that contains tons of JS code. Another problem with that implementation for my case (and maybe that's because I've implemented things wrong) is that I use the current page `@model` to use some data from the Controller in the JS script:

```
// Parse all sites and cities from model and populate map with markers
cities = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Cities))');
sites = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Sites))');
```

So, if I would to transition that Javascript code to another file, **how could I access the Model information from that file?**

Another thing I'm sure I'm doing wrong is I'm also using Json.Serialize in the .cshtml part to pass values as arguments to a Javascript function:

```
<button onclick='selectMarker(null,@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Site)))'
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action justify-content-between align-items-start d-flex w-100" 
        style="cursor: pointer; outline: none;">
```

That makes the page HTML super ugly and also exposes some information about the "Site" I would prefer not to be displayed like that.